# Java XPath Api : handling dynamic namespace prefixes

Tags: xpath, namespaces

I am using the java XPath API to extract values from Xml nodes. 
My Xpaths (e.g 'A/B/C') are pre-defined in a file. 
However the xml can be created by multiple source systems and as a result the namespace prefixes might differ.

The evaluate method doesn't seem to work without the prefix and I do not have any way to know the prefix before runtime as it might differ.

I tried using local-name but in that case the Xpath has to be stored as //*[local-name()='C']. However for clarity I would like to keep it as A/B/C.

Could you please suggest a way out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post your code as an example of what you are currently doing.

Comment: The prefixes in the input XML do not really matter, the namespace an element or attribute belongs to matters. Thus if the namespace(s) are always the same you can set up your Java code with a `NamespaceContext` where you predefine your own chosen prefix(es) for the expected input namespaces and then your path expressions can use those prefixes. On the other hand you say you want the have paths like `A/B/C` without prefixes, in that case you would need to use an XPath 2.0 implementation anyway. So you need to explain in more detail how your input looks and which Java API you use.